# creating user login in derby js

Tags: derbyjs

It seems that basic functionality such as user login, can not be done in simple manner: to have username and password field in form on client and based on that to create store.readPathAccess model access rights. Also, how to check if user is logged in to implement access rights on routes?

Based on examples and (poor) DerbyJS documentation, if I understood it correctly, you have to implement login in server module (lib/server/*) because:

1. store.readPathAccess must be used in server side
2. you want to store data in model session (which can be read only on server side)

But many questions arise:

1. if it has to be done on server side, how to get and store client form data on server side without having problem with second item below on the list (I have done it with manually submitting data to server-only route, but can not then save it in model with local key because I have to redirect to client route after that and local model data is lost)
2. how to read later that data if it must be stored in session?
3. even if the store access rights for model is managed, how to check if this specific user is logged in when in client routes?

I'm quite confused at the moment... liked Derby principles, but this authentication problems are playing with my nerves seriously.

I know I may not be quite clear, but there are many points to go in details and if anyone can help I'll gladly give more required info.

Thank you,
Eddie

Comment: see https://github.com/derbyparty/derby-login they have a few examples and make authentication pretty simple, even giving register and login components.

Answer (score 2):

I found this library today called [derby-auth](https://github.com/lefnire/derby-auth).
It uses passport for signing in and has a good example using a simple register and login form.
What it does is to set some routes on the server for logging the user, and a middleware to tell the client if it's logged or not.
It does have some bugs (a few callback calls missing that break some things), so i wrote my own based on that, but must clean a lot of things before uploading anywhere.
i'd be glad to send it to you if you want to, though.

Answer (score 0):

The most current library is https://github.com/derbyparty/derby-login

It has been updated pretty regularly and works with derbyjs 0.6